# Por que função de incremento de variável não funciona em AngularJS? Não estou acessando a variável corretamente?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Olá. Preciso alterar o valor de uma variável em angularJS porém estou encontrando o seguinte problema: "Cannot set property 'quantidade' of undefined".

Ao clicar no botão *add*, preciso que a variável *quantidade* contida em *mercadoria1* seja acrescida em 1.

Botão html:

```html
<button ng-show="someAdicionar" class="add" ng-click = "adicionar();">+</button>
```

Abaixo a forma como tentei e em toda pesquisa a solução sugerida é esta abaixo.

código AngularJS:

```html
.controller('mercadoriaCarrinho', function ($rootScope, $http){
  $rootScope.listademercadoria=[];

  $rootScope.mercadoria1 = {
   id: '55',
   setor: 'alimento',
   foto: 'Produtos/Produto (55).jpg',
   descr: 'Macarr�o Renata',
   de: 15,
   por: 12,
   mercadoria: '1',
   quantidade: 1
  }
  $rootScope.listademercadoria.push($rootScope.mercadoria1);

  $rootScope.adicionar = function (){
   {   
    $rootScope.listademercadoria.mercadoria1.quantidade=$rootScope.listademercadoria.mercadoria1.quantidade+1;
   }      
  }
});
```

Ressalto que funções de outro tipo, de outros botões paralelos a este, estão funcionando corretamente, porém somente esta função está com este problema.

Comment: É uma péssima prática armazenar dados no `$rootScope`

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Considerando que eu armazene no $Scope, teria solução este meu problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está tentando acessar uma posição do `array` pelo nome da variável em que os valores são definidos. Para acessar um item de `array` você deve utilizar a posição, ou mudar para um `Object`:

```
$rootScope.listademercadoria = {};

// ... Definição do objeto

$rootScope.listademercadoria.mercadoria1 = $rootScope.mercadoria1;
```

Ou:

```
$rootScope.adicionar = function (){
  $rootScope.listademercadoria[0].quantidade = $rootScope.listademercadoria[0].quantidade + 1;
}
```

**Observação:** Utilizar o `$rootScope` para armazenar variáveis não é uma boa prática. Se quer compartilhar dados com outros `controllers` utilize um `service` ou `factory`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Funcionou. Poderia me dizer o porquê de não ser uma boa prática?

Comment: @GuilhermeSilvadeOliveira Dá uma olhada [neste tópico](https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-servico-ou-rootscope-19568).